# Microbroth dilution

Tags: microbiology, mycology, antibiotics

I have performed MIC test for fungi candida albicans, Cryptococcus neoformans and Aspergillus fumigatus in a 96 well plate by broth microdilution method by drugs Amphotericin B and fluconazole..followed was picking up colonies just after the result i.e. after MIC test.. the next well with growth to be plated onto SDA plates then after incubation and further growth..now I have been asked to transfer them to SDB (500ml) in flasks..I would like to know why is this done..thankyou.